# How to create screenshot of a telegram post widget (inside generated iframe) only with client-side JS?

Tags: javascript, iframe, telegram, html2canvas, webpage-screenshot

I want to create screenshot of the telegram widget and put it on a page. Link to [code is here.](https://jsfiddle.net/nibezo/agre205d/12/); Also I easily did screenshot of iframe using devtools "create node screenshot", is any JS method to do the same from the code? (I tried google it, but found nothing).
HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Telegram widget</title>
</head>
<body>
      <script src="https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/dist/html2canvas.min.js"></script>

  <script async src="https://telegram.org/js/telegram-widget.js?22" data-telegram-post="telegram/83" data-width="100%"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```js
window.onload = function() {
      var iframe = document.getElementById('telegram-post-telegram-83');
      var iframeDocument = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;

      html2canvas(iframeDocument.body).then(function(canvas) {
        document.body.appendChild(canvas);
      });
    };
```

I tried access to iframe body, but this is not working. I got error:

```html
"<a class='gotoLine' href='#61:75'>61:75</a> Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to read a named property 'document' from 'Window': Blocked a frame with origin \&quot;https://fiddle.jshell.net\&quot; from accessing a cross-origin frame."
```